# How to send SOAP digital signed message using cert

Tags: php, xml, soap, sign, xmlseclibs

I want to sign an XML document using certificate. It should looks like:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:obs="http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-UUU09456789100000">XXXX==</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="obs soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-XYZXYZ1234567890000"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="obs" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>vVYVY4CXo60TYkSZ8S/LQJo/8Zc=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>SIGNATURExxxx</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-UUU09456789100000" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-XYZXYZ1234567890000" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <obs:zapiszKomunikatOS>

          <komunikatOS>
              ...
          </komunikatOS>

      </obs:zapiszKomunikatOS>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried to use an XMLSecLibs but unfortunatelly it doesn't work well. The first, I don't know how to add inclusive-namespaces with that tool and maybe that is the key for properly signing? I also tried to copy the digest value and signature value with changing the references to above template, but it doesn't work (I've got message from SOAP server: "A security error was encountered when verifying the message Caused by: The signature or decryption was invalid").

There is some ugly code tries to sign:

```php
$communicateFile = __DIR__ . 'template-3.xml';
$pemFilePrv = __DIR__ . '/../cert/15.pem';
$xml = trim(file_get_contents($communicateFile));

$wsseNamespace = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
$wsuNamespace = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->load($communicateFile);

$xp = new \DOMXPath($doc);

$xp->registerNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'); 

$xp->registerNamespace('wsse',$wsseNamespace);
$xp->registerNamespace('wsu',$wsuNamespace);
$xp->registerNamespace('ds',XMLSecurityDSig::XMLDSIGNS);

$securityNode = $xp->query('//wsse:Security')->item(0);
$bodyNode = $xp->query('//soapenv:Body')->item(0);

$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::EXC_C14N);
$objDSig->addReference($bodyNode, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1,NULL, 
    array('prefix'=>'wsu','prefix_ns'=>$wsuNamespace)); 

$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));
$objKey->passphrase = 'XXXXX';
$objKey->loadKey($pemFilePrv, TRUE);
$objDSig->sign($objKey);

$objDSig->insertSignature($securityNode);
```

Could anyone help me? Maybe there is only missing an incluseNamespaces? I count on you, becouse I'm out of ideas..

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

This example is a project of its own that is in production. I hope I can help you.

```
$context = stream_context_create([ 
    'ssl' => [ 
        'verify_peer' => false, 
        'verify_peer_name' => false, 
        'local_cert' =>  LOCAL_CERT, 
        'passphrase' => PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE 
    ] 
]); 

$client = new BinarySignedSoapClient($wsdl , ['trace' => 1, 'stream_context' => $context]);
```

Call to:

```
class BinarySignedSoapClient extends \SoapClient 
{ 

    function __construct($wsdl, $context, $params) { 
      $this->crt_cert_file = array_key_exists('crt_cert_file', $params) ? $params['crt_cert_file'] : null; 
      $this->private_key_passphrase = array_key_exists('private_key_passphrase', $params) ? $params['private_key_passphrase'] : null; 
      $this->private_key_file = array_key_exists('private_key_file', $params) ? $params['private_key_file'] : null; 
      parent::__construct($wsdl, $context); 
    } 

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version, $one_way = 0) 
    { 

        $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0'); 
        $doc->loadXML($request); 

        $objWSSE = new \WSSESoap($doc); 

        /* add Timestamp with no expiration timestamp */ 
        $objWSSE->addTimestamp(); 

        /* create new XMLSec Key using RSA_SHA1 and type is private key */ 
        $objKey = new \XMLSecurityKey(\XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, ['type' => 'private']); 

        /* load the private key from file - last arg is bool if key in file (true) or is string (false) */ 
        $objKey->passphrase = $this->private_key_passphrase; 
        $objKey->loadKey(__DIR__ ."/../localssl/". $this->private_key_file, true, false); 

        /* Sign the message - also signs appropiate WS-Security items */ 
        $options = array("insertBefore" => false); 
        $objWSSE->signSoapDoc($objKey, $options); 

        /* Add certificate (BinarySecurityToken) to the message */ 
        $token = $objWSSE->addBinaryToken(file_get_contents(__DIR__ ."/../localssl/". $this->crt_cert_file)); 

        /* Attach pointer to Signature */ 
        $objWSSE->attachTokentoSig($token); 
        $retVal = parent::__doRequest($objWSSE->saveXML(), $location, $saction, $version); 

        $doc = new \DOMDocument(); 
        $doc->loadXML($retVal); 

        $options = ["keys" => ["private" => ["key" => __DIR__ . $this->private_key_file, "isFile" => true, "isCert" => false]]]; 
        $objWSSE->decryptSoapDoc($doc, $options); 


        return $doc->saveXML(); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ezequiel, your solution is pretty useful - it generates the whole wsse header, which is great, but the SOAP server still refuses the whole message "The signature or decryption was invalid". I see a little difference - in generated XML by WSSESoap there is no inclusiveNamespace tag and valueType for binarySecurityToken is different (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3 instead of http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1), so the value of token is also different than from sopui

Comment: I also used soapui and the token was the same. I completed the previous example in case it helps you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the amazing answer! I Googled the classes you used and found this library: https://github.com/robrichards/wse-php and installed it with composer and made it work with the code in `examples/soap-wsa-example.php` I just had to adapt it to PHP7 a little bit.